# C: Placing and using malloc

Tags: c, linux

Trying to understand what's wrong with the following code:

```
int main (void){
    char *s;
    s=(char*)malloc(15);
    s="Hello World";
    free(s);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well, first you cause a memory leak by changing the address `s` is pointing to from the allocated memory to a string literal, and then you try to `free` a string literal, so undefined behavior.

Comment: To copy strings you should use `strcpy()` or `strncpy()` from `string.h`

Comment: You need to study how pointers work before moving on to malloc.

Answer (score 3):

`s="Hello World";` does not copy the string into `s`. It changes the value of `s` to point to the string (technically the first character of the string).

Then `s` is no longer pointing to the memory allocated by `malloc`, so passing its new value to `free` is wrong because it asks `free` to release something that `malloc` never allocated.

In C source code, a string in quotation marks is a *string literal*. It results in the creation of an array of characters containing the characters from the source code, terminated by a null character. The memory for that array is reserved when the program starts executing and remains reserved for all of program execution. (This is called *static* storage duration and is separate from the *allocated* memory provided by `malloc`.)

Whenever an array is used in an expression other than the operand of `sizeof` or of unary `&` or as a string literal used to initialize in array (in a definition), it is automatically converted to a pointer to its first element. So, in `s="Hello World";`, the array created by `"Hello World"` is automatically converted to a pointer to the “H” that has been stored for the string literal. Then `s="Hello World";` changes `s` to this pointer.

To copy the string into the memory pointed to by `s`, you can use `strcpy(s, "Hello World");`, or you can write your own code to copy the bytes one-by-one from the string literal into the memory pointed to by `s`.

Answer (score 0):

You try to copy your string like a character, but you can't in C. You should use the function [strcpy](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strcpy);

```c
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *s = malloc(15);

    strcpy(s, "Hello World");
    free(s);
    return 0;
}
```

Moreover you can use the function [strdup](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strdup) to duplicate a string like that:

```c
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *s = strdup("Hello World");

    free(s);
    return 0;
}
```

The function strdup allocate memory and copy byte per byte the source in the destination, then return the destination.

Comment: Small note: `strdup` isn't standard C yet (though I think it was proposed for C2x)